# How to ensure that all observers see the same result from multiple parallel subscription

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

I have two observables.
First - get session from internet or from cache;

```
Observable<SessionKey> getSession = getSessionFromInternetOrCache();
```

Second - call to server api, using session

```
Observable<MyResult> apiCall = getSession.flatMap(session -> {
    return myApi.getResult(session);
})
```

Problem, that I have several independent components (gui). They are starting in parallel. `apiCall` also started in parallel. And i gets several session keys.

What behavior I want: `getSessions` should calling once, other observables waiting first `getSessions` call. After first `getSessions` calling, all `getSessions` will be return cached session;

What idea to implement that behaviour?

**UPD**
Behavior should be: Retrieving session from internet should block other getSessions calls, until session not will be cached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `cache()` on the returned Observable in `getSessionFromInternetOrCache` and it will make sure the session will be retrieved only once and replayed to anyone trying to observe it later. I assume the actual session retrieval only happens when one subscribes to the Observable.

**Edit**: this example shows what I meant:

```
public class SingleSessions {
    static Observable<String> getSession;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        getSession =
                Observable.just("abc")
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> System.out.println("This should happen once")) 
                .delay(500 + new Random().nextInt(2) * 700, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Observable.just("cde"))
                .cache();

        System.out.println("Asking for the session key");

        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);
        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);
        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);
        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("Sleeping...");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("...done");

        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);
        getSession.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem that `getSessions ` calls in parallel. Every gui component has own Subscriber.