# rxjava synchronize on one observable

Tags: concurrency, rx-java

On each network request I have logic to do authorization if needed and repeat initial request. Operator retryWhen used for this. Simplistically, it looks like this:

doRequestObservable().retryWhen(getLoginObservable()).subcribe(...)

But when there are a lot of parallel requests - a lot of parallel authorizations sends on server.
How I can prevent multiply authorization in such case?
In right way only for first failed request must be done authorization, next failed request must repated without authorization request.

I can add synchronization in getLoginObservable() method, but may be there are some better method?

Comment: Please provide some more code. If you use flatMap somethere, use overload: ,1 to max concurrency to one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ensure that all observers see the same result from multiple parallel subscription](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30756552/how-to-ensure-that-all-observers-see-the-same-result-from-multiple-parallel-subs)